Fastify aditional opts messes up schema validation typings
Once I add a preHandler, or any other property to opts param, req.body type becomes unkown, I would like to know if this is a known issue or if there's a workaround, I though of calling zod.parse inside the function but I want to keep the type-safe validation
    .withTypeProvider<ZodTypeProvider>()
    .post('/', 
    { 
        preHandler: [authRequired], schema: { body: createTrackValidator }
    }, 
    (req) => {
        
        return trackService.createTrack(req.body, req.user.id);
    });

